# How can I improve my turns when downhill skiing?

Tags: skiing

*How can I improve my turns when downhill skiing?*

Whenever I make passes back and forth, my uphill ski is at an angle and is awkward, often causing me to stumble.  I would have much better control if I could learn to turn **both** skis at the same time and keep them aligned.

Answer (score 5):

You will need both Technical and strength drills.

You should strengthen your core/torso strength, as that's where most of the movement is coming from, using drills such as squat, lunges, wall seat and more (you can see a good [list here](http://www.epicski.com/a/exercises-for-pre-season-ski-training)).

You will also need to improve your technical aspect of the movement (I assume you mean your carving of the snow with both legs - what's called: Parallel ski). There are some gym exercises with specific equipment that can help you master the movement.

Answer (score 2):

I am a learning skier as well and generally that happens when I involuntarily lean, even slightly, back on turns especially when on harder slopes. 
Make sure you are turning in the correct position, you have pressure on the front of your boots.